# React native Modal, avoid resizing View when keyboard is opened (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, view, keyboard, modal-dialog

I'm using a react-native Modal, which contains a View.
The View has some TextInput elements. When the keyboard pops up, the View elements all collapse to fit into the remaining space, but I don't want the View to change at all.

This does **not** happen for IOS. And also, it does **not** happen in non-modal Views for Android within the same app.

I have windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" set in my android Manifest, but it doesn't seem to be applied on the Modal.

```
return( 
<ImageBackground source={require('./../images/IMG1.png')}
        style={{flex: 1}} imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'cover'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
     (...)
     <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible} animationType={'slide'} 
        presentationStyle={'fullScreen'}
        onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal()}>

        <ImageBackground source={require('./../images/IMG2.png')}
          style={{flex: 1}} imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'cover'}}>

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>

          (...)

          <View style={{flex:0.9, alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center', 
                                                  flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TextInput style={MyStyle.textInput}
                onChangeText={(myTitle) => this.setState({myTitle})}
                placeholder='Title'
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping the View in a ScrollView?

Comment: Are you adding `keyboardAvoidingView` anywhere?, it would be helpful if the relevant code is provided.

Comment: I have updated the code (not including closing tags or other non-relevant elements). Yes I did try a ScrollView, but when opening the modal, the screen elements are already collapsed without even opening the keyboard at all (so when I open the keyboard, the result is exactly the same).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a workaround, I ended up using a fixed height value for the Modal’s child View instead of flex. (Got it using Dimensions height).
It seems to work as I expected.

Comment: @tfmontague You get the screen height like this: `var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window'); this.setState({screenHeight: height});`  And then style your element using that height: `style={{height: this.state.screenHeight }}`

Comment: I have the same problem. However, it is the modal view that is resizing, so even if I use fixed height for modal's child view, it just remains within the resized modal view.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like you need to apply `statusBarTranslucent={true}` prop for the `Modal` to make the modal content not to resize and the keyboard to pan over the modal content.

Comment: This is the correct answer, adding Height, or not using flex is not the answer.. They don't work.

Comment: But this will show background in while using bottom navigator

Answer (score 1):

My workaround: I used the following style for the child of the modal.

```
container: {
    left: 50,
    position: "absolute",
    right: 50,
    top: 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  Modal,
  ImageBackground,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    myTitle: '',
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./../images/IMG1.png')}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'cover' }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {/* ... Other content ... */}
          <Modal
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            animationType={'slide'}
            presentationStyle={'fullScreen'}
            onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal()}
          >
            <ImageBackground
              source={require('./../images/IMG2.png')}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'cover' }}
            >
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
                accessible={false}
              >
                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                  behavior="height"
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                >
                  {/* ... Other modal content ... */}
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flex: 0.9,
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                    }}
                  >
                    <TextInput
                      style={MyStyle.textInput}
                      onChangeText={(myTitle) =>
                        this.setState({ myTitle })
                      }
                      placeholder="Title"
                    />
                  </View>
                  {/* ... More modal content ... */}
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </ImageBackground>
          </Modal>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```