# On keyboard open: modal cuts from down and seems bad, don't know why

Tags: api, react-native, mobile, modal-dialog

I am using `Modal` from `react-native-modal` library. Modal was opening in full screen so i did `marginVertical: 280` to display modal in half screen, but the issue is when keyboard opens then modal cuts from down and looks very bad. Here are some screenshots:

Without open keyboard:
[image: Click to see screenshot of without open keyboard]

With open keyboard:
[image: Click to see screenshot of when keyboard opens]

Here is the code:
**app.js**

```
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import { Container, Content, Item, Input, Text, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';
import { Grid, Col } from 'react-native-easy-grid';

class VansFilterModal extends Component {

  getFilterModal() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.modal}>
        <Grid>
          <Col style={{ width: '7%' }}>
            <Icon name="dot-circle-o" type="FontAwesome" />
          </Col>
          <Col style={{ width: '75%' }}>
            <Item rounded>
              <Input
                value={values.pickupLocation}
                onChangeText={handleChange('pickupLocation')}
                placeholder="Pick up location"
              />
            </Item>
          </Col>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const filterModal = this.getFilterModal();
    const { visibleVansFilter, hideVansFilter } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          isVisible={visibleVansFilter}
          onBackdropPress={() => hideVansFilter()}
          style={styles.bottomModal}
        >
          {filterModal}
        </Modal>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**styles.js**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modal: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "#C0C0C0",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    marginVertical: 180,
    marginTop: 0
  },
  bottomModal: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    margin: 0,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it can be solved by setting fixed height value as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166110/5744394). Let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: I didn't understand that answer. i did height: 300 instead of flex:1 , but no work